# RSA encryption in JavaScript with available modulus

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have some Java code that sends the public exponent and modulus (very, very long integer)  via json to the javascript.

I need to apply RSA encryption on a text field (password) using these values in JavaScript.

I have tried many available things on net but no success yet. And I don't have SSL in the application.

Can someone please help me on this? Some sample/exact code will be a blessing.

Comment: I assumed you're talking about JavaScript, not Java. Note that they are not the same thing.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks. I edited the body also. I need encryption in javascript and I have the decryption in java.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I thought you were using both for the same thing. You're completely correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked out http://code.google.com/p/jscryptolib/ ?

Alternatively there is another implementation here: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

You can find a demo of the second implementation here: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa.html - just view source to see how it's used

Comment: Thanks Martin. But jscrypto demo never mentions rsa. The demo html not even loads the RSA script.maybe I am missing something,  but I found it a mess. Will try the other one..

Comment: Try to look under the header "Supported Cryptography Algorithms", there you will find the line "Public key cryptography: RSA, DSA, ECC, CPK, IBE" which does mention RSA :)